# Выбрать ряд с максимальным значением из подзапроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Использую Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio

Вот код запроса

```
Select  Sections.[Section Type], Sum(Equipment.price)
FROM MRP
INNER JOIN Equipment ON Equipment.UserId=MRP.Id
INNER JOIN Sections ON MRP.[Section Type]=Sections.[Section Type]
GROUP BY Sections.[Section Type]
GO
```

Нужно найти ряд с максимальным элементом из

```
Sum(Equipment.price)
```

Из этого

[image: Картинка запроса]

Получить вот такое

[image: Картинка запорса ответа]

Comment: Какая СУБД используется? Очевидно, что нужен `order by` Sum(Equipment.price) с получением только 1го результата (типа limit 1)

Comment: Судя по квадратным скобкам, это то ли MS Access, то ли SQL Server. Тогда просто добавить `SELECT TOP 1 ...` и `ORDER BY 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ

```
Select TOP 1 Sections.[Section Type], Sum(Equipment.price) 
FROM MRP
INNER JOIN Equipment ON Equipment.UserId=MRP.Id
INNER JOIN Sections ON MRP.[Section Type]=Sections.[Section Type]
GROUP BY Sections.[Section Type]
Order by Sum(Equipment.price) DESC
```